# relation between 'course' and 'discourse'

Tags: word-meaning, word-difference

I am always confused by these similar words.

Do they have the same meaning in some case?

If not, why are they so similar to each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do not have the same meaning, but there are similarities in some of their respective meanings, and they have common etymological origin.

## 1. Meaning similarity:

- course: a series of lectures or lessons in a particular subject, typically leading to a qualification.
- discourse: a formal discussion of a topic in speech or writing.

## 2. Etymological origin

- course:

[image]

- discourse:

[image]